# Como uso o AddEventListener() no vueJs

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Estou fazendo uma função do meu projeto e preciso de usar o evento `addEventListener()` mas esta dando um erro:

```js
excluirVariante:function(v){
    console.log(this.$el.querySelector('#op_nao'));
    console.log(this.$el.querySelector('#op_sim'));
    $('#model_permissao').modal('show');
    console.log(v);
    this.$el.querySelector("#op_sim").addEventListener("click",function(){
        this.lista_variante.find(function(el,i,list){
            if(el===v){
                list.splice(i,1);
                console.log('foi');
            }
        });
    },false);
    this.$el.querySelector('#op_nao').addEventListener('click',function(){
        $('#model_permissao').model('hide');
    },false);
},
```

---

**Esse é o erro:**

> app.js:14719 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>           at VueComponent.excluirVariante (app.js:14719)
>           at Proxy.boundFn (app.js:27396)
>           at click (app.js:18030)
>           at HTMLElement.invoker (app.js:28969)

Comment: A função excluirVariante é executada quando clicada em um botão?

Comment: Você está tentando atribuir um evento a um elemento que não existe, pelo menos um dos seus `querySelector` está retornando `null`. Além disso, está estranho o jeito que você está fazendo as coisas, no Vue.js raramente é preciso manipular o DOM manualmente dessa maneira.